# Calculator parse user input using regex

Tags: java, regex, string

Have the next regex `/+|-^[(-]`, which I use in String.split(regex) method.

I want to split in situations when there is plus or minus, but if it's minus then don't split if before him there is opening parentheses.

Correct example: `toDollar(-45euro)-$30    ---->    { toDollar(-45euro) , $30 }`.

So my regex doesn't follow this rule, how to modify it ?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/33 is this a valid input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for is a negative lookbehind:

```
\\+|(?<!\\()-
```

`(?<!...)` is the [lookbehind](http://regular-expressions.com/lookaround.html) and means "not preceded by ..."